# Why does $\frac{3}{4} \times 1\frac{1}{3}$ equal $1$?

Tags: fractions, percentages

Can someone please explain how this works and how to apply it to other fractions to get 100%?

I thought it might have something to do with the Dividend in the first Part (In this Example the 3 in $\frac34$) being the divisor in the second part (The $3$ in $1\frac13$) since $\frac56 \times 1\frac{1}{5}$ also equals $1$ but it doesn't really work out with other Fractions like $\frac46$.

Maybe those two examples have by pure coincidence so nicely even and fitting numbers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot 1\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}=1$$ holds for every positive integer $n$. So, this is no coincidence.

Comment: If we replace $n+1$ by $n+2$ this of course does not work anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align}
1\frac{1}{a} &= 1 + \frac{1}{a} \\
&= \frac{a}{a} + \frac{1}{a} \\
&= \frac{a+1}{a}.
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a}{a+1} \times 1\frac{1}{a} &= \frac{a}{a+1} \times \frac{a+1}{a} \\
&= 1,
\end{align}$$

provided $a\neq 0$ and $a \ne -1$

Comment: Thanks, replacing it with Variables really helps understanding what's going on. It also explains why $\frac 46$ doesn't work since it would result in $\mathit a + 2$ and i only replaced one of two occurrences in my previous train of thought. But i think i stay with the classic ways calculating to 100% (or 1). This is waay to confusing to calculate in the Head XD

Answer (score 3):

The intuition of *multiplying with a fraction* is:

> Take that fraction out of the other factor!

E.g. multiplying $x$ by $1/2$ means taking a half of $x$. Multiplying $x$ by $3/5$ means taking three fifths of $x$. And so on.

Now, you are multiplying $3/4$ by $1\frac{1}{3}$, which may mean one of two things, which will *both boil down to the same*:

- Either you are taking three quarters of $1\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4}{3}$. In this case, one quarter of it is $1/3$ and three quarters are $3/3=1$,
- Or you are taking one-and-a-third of $3/4$. A third of $3/4$ is $1/4$ so one-and-a-third of $3/4$ is $3/4+1/4=4/4=1$.

In both cases, the result is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1\,\frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$, you get
$$\frac{3}{4}\times 1\,\frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{3} = 1.$$
For your other example,
$$\frac{4}{6}\times 1\,\frac{\color{red}{2}}{4} = \frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{6}{4} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here

$$\begin{align}
1\frac{1}{3}&=\frac{3}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\\
&=\frac{3+1}{3}\\
&=\frac{4}{3};
\end{align}$$

therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{3}{4}\times 1\frac{1}{3}&=\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{4}{3}\\
&=\frac{3\times 4}{4\times 3}\\
&=\frac{12}{12}\\
&=1.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1\frac{1}{3}$ is the same as $1+\frac{1}{3}$.  Therefore, we can rewrite the product as
$$
\frac{3}{4}\times\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right).
$$
Now, we can use the distributive property to rewrite this as
$$
\frac{3}{4}\times 1+\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}.
$$
The first product is $\frac{3}{4}$ since we have multiplication by $1$.  The second product simplifies to $\frac{1}{4}$ since there is a $3$ in the numerator and a $3$ in the denominator, which cancel.  Putting this together, this simplifies to
$$
\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3+1}{4}=1.
$$